# Where can I find the resources to learn how to develop plug ins/add ons for Windows Onenote?

Tags: onenote

I want to make a plug in or an add on for the windows OneNote application but all I can find is the OneNote API. Correct me if I'm wrong but that API is not to make an add on so I need some other resource that I can learn from.

For example, creating something that will manipulate the text in OneNote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a COM API that you can use that works with Windows OneNote.  Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj680118.aspx

Separately there is an open source sample here: https://github.com/onenotedev/vanillaaddin

This is for a plugin for OneNote. It is also possible to do this as an external Windows or console app.